# How to resolve error 0xc000007b opening Adobe After Effects?

Tags: windows-8, adobe-after-effects

I have installed Adobe CS6 on Windows 8 and get the error "0xc000007b" every time I open open Adobe After Effects. All other Adobe software, including Photoshop and Premiere Pro work perfectly. I have looked online extensively but have not found any solutions.

What can I try/do to resolve this error?

Best regards, Manu

OS: Windows 8 (64 bit) - CPU: Intel Core i3-3110M 2,40GHz - RAM: 6GB DD3 - FX: AMD Radeon HD 7670M

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Microsoft Security Essentials?  The only thing I can find online about it is something that says that it detects a critical file for After Effects as a malware threat.  You may have to tell it to ignore the file.  It is amtlib.dll that it will detect.  You may or may not have to reinstall after you tell it that the file is safe.

Comment: There is also a video that explains more details about it if you Google "after effects 0xc000007b".